# Create an audio source and assign a clip in Unity

Tags: audio, unity-game-engine, unityscript

Folks I'm having trouble creating an audio source and assigning it a clip in Unity.

I'm streaming a file and the debugger tells me it's found the file and it's ready to play using the following code.

```
@script RequireComponent(AudioSource)

var www : WWW;
var audioSource: AudioSource = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
var myAudioClip: AudioClip;


function Start ()
{
      www = new WWW ("file://" + Application.dataPath.Substring (0, Application.dataPath.LastIndexOf ("/")) + "/Assets/intro.wav"); 
      myAudioClip = www.audioClip;
      Debug.Log(myAudioClip.isReadyToPlay);
}
```

However the debugger gives me errors in my audioSource declaration.

```
Unexpected Token: )
expecting ), found ';'
'; expected, insert a semicolon at the end.
```

This error points at the line

var audioSource: AudioSource = gameObject.AddComponent();

Ultimately my aim is to then assign the clip to the audioSource and let rip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have declared that a component of AudioSource is needed;

```
@script RequireComponent(AudioSource)
```

So no need to add it as a component. I don't normally use UnityScript but here's the code you want;

```
@script RequireComponent(AudioSource)

var www             : WWW;
var audioSource : AudioSource;
var myAudioClip : AudioClip;

function Start () {
    audioSource = GetComponent(AudioSource);
    StartCoroutine( LoadAudio( "file://" + Application.dataPath.Substring (0, Application.dataPath.LastIndexOf ("/")) + "/Assets/intro.wav" ) );
}

function LoadAudio( path : String ) {
    www = new WWW ( path );
    yield www;
    myAudioClip = www.audioClip;
    Debug.Log(myAudioClip.isReadyToPlay);
}
```

To use the WWW class you can use coroutines to wait until it's done loading the asset you require. Or you can keep checking whether www.isDone is true.

Documentation; http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html

Comment: Thanks a million for taking the time to look at this Josh! I'll give this a try later today and come back to you.

Comment: Worked a treat, thanks Josh! The path : string declaration required camelcase String but other than that perfect!

Comment: Glad I could help. I'll fix that up